# BitBlt causes a glitch when called after EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to take a screenshot of the foreground window.

To do that, I use `SetWinEventHook()` (listening to `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND`) and `BitBlt()`. It's working as expected, except for **newly created** windows which shows up not fully rendered (transparent parts):

[image]

**Adding** a 10~50ms **delay** between the `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` event and `BitBlt()` "solves" the problem.

The issue happens randomly and only to some windows. Can someone explain what's happening and how to properly fix this?

Here's a minimal reproduceable example:

```
VOID CALLBACK WinEventProcCallback(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD dwEvent, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if (dwEvent == EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND && hwnd)
    {
        // Sleep(20); // This "solves" the issue
        HDC dcScreen = GetDC(hwnd);
        HDC dcTarget = CreateCompatibleDC(dcScreen);
        HBITMAP bmpTarget = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcScreen, 100, 100);
        HGDIOBJ oldBmp = SelectObject(dcTarget, bmpTarget);
        BitBlt(dcTarget, 0, 0, 100, 100, dcScreen, 100, 100, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
        SelectObject(dcTarget, oldBmp);
        DeleteDC(dcTarget);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, dcScreen);
    }
  
}

int main()
{   
    SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, NULL, WinEventProcCallback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageA(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: WM_PRINT instead? RedrawWindow(..., RDW_UPDATENOW)?

Comment: @Anders: Yes, using `PrintWindow()` or calling `RedrawWindow(..RDW_UPDATENOW)`  (or simply `UpdateWindow()`) before `BitBlt()` solves the issue. Please add your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` might notify from deep inside the foreground change code in the window manager and the new foreground window might still be waiting to paint by the time you `BitBlt`.

Call `RedrawWindow(.., RDW_UPDATENOW)` or `UpdateWindow` first to make the window paint its invalid areas.